# MJPEG format not working

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, codec

Gphoto2 captures live preview frames from cameras and store them as a MJPEG encoded movie.

For some reason, nothing besides ffmpeg works with it as it should, all programs just see the first JPG frame (as an still JPG image) and nothing more. I can convert it through ffmpeg, but this should not be necessary.

I'm trying to use Gstreamer (with gst-launch-0.10) but all options render the same thing: It only sees the first frame of the MJPEG.

Is this normal?

Is there any way i can configure gphoto2 to use another format, or use ffmpeg to pipeline the decoded frames to gst-launch?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the command line you're using to generate the MJPEG movie?

Comment: @heavyd, i just use "gphoto2 --capture-movie", that's the default format it uses, and i don't think i can choose another format (at least i couldn't find it on the documentation)

Comment: In my brief look at gphoto2, it doesn't look like its really capturing a MJPEG movie, its just appending JPEG images sequentially into a single file.  FFMPEG is pretty forgiving, so it works, but other tools are not so nice.

Comment: Can you provide a sample file?